# convert string to an object based on Type

Tags: c#

```
Type type1 = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
string test = "test";
```

please let me know how  to convert the test to an object based on type1 object.
And it should fail or return null as the given string cannot be converted to int.

This for validation purpose.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? If it is just to see if a string is an int then Boas' answer is correct. This sounds like an X-Y problem

Comment: Why don't you know the type at compile time? That seems to be the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if i understand you right.

if you want to safely convert a string to int see

```
int result;
bool wasConverted;
wasConverted = int.TryParse(test,out result)
```

For more generic conversion ahve a look at the ConvertClass.

For Example [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) but there you would have to handle exceptions your own way.

```
public object SafeConvertChangeType(object value,Type targetType)
      {
      object result ;
      try {
           result = Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
      }
      catch (FormatException)
      catch (InvalidCastException) {
           result = null;
      }
return result;
}
```

you can that call the method this was:

```
var result = SafeConvertChangeType("Foo",typeof(int32));
```

You may also have a loot at this [post: Test if Convert.ChangeType will work between two types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399273/test-if-convert-changetype-will-work-between-two-types). It points out that there is no "ConversionCheck" Api. So I assumed you would need that exception catch

Comment: instead of exception ,is there any other method which returns null if the conversion fails??

Comment: i change the example you can wrap it in your own method to do that

Comment: i guess it throws Formatexception when converting string to Int..so need to add catch with formatexception as well??correct me if im wrong??

Comment: well it depdends s. MSDN article. In deed both exceptions could occur so you would have to catch both

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Type type1 = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
string test = "test";
object newObject = Convert.ChangeType(test, type1);
```

Comment: Be aware that this throws an exception withi invalid value, he wants to make safe transformations. So you shoul add an try catch (like in my example)

Comment: The question states it should fail or return null. So both allowed.

Comment: oh yeah sorry my fault. i missread it

Comment: thanks for your answers ,but can you please lemme know if we there is way to return null instead of exception,may not possible with Changetype...but any other way???

Comment: Just use a try ... catch.

Comment: yeah i understood that but instead of exception ,is there any other method which returns null if the conversion fails??

Comment: There isn't one. Sorry...

Comment: @PatrickHofman please lemme know if its possible to know the datatype of the value stored in the test object....

Comment: Just call `test.GetType()`

Comment: you can set it to null in the Catch and wrap taht in your on method "SafeChangeType()" s. my post below