# Check conversion of type string to other types

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, string-conversion

I am using reflection and I want to do conversion checking for exception handling.

**I need to check if string can convert to unknown type in my project.**

I used :

```
TypeConverter t = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(string));
            Console.WriteLine(t.CanConvertTo(typeof(int)));
```

but it returns false !

or even this one returns false again :

```
StringConverter stringConverter = new StringConverter();
            Console.WriteLine(stringConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(int)));
```

my quesion is that **why StringConverter returns false for converting string to int** ???

**EDIT :**

I use this code to convert string to unknown types : ( result is string )

```
resultCastedToTargetPropertyType = Convert.ChangeType(result,propertyInfo.PropertyType);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you would use to convert a string to an int?

Comment: [StringConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.stringconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) This converter can only convert **to** a string.

Comment: What does `TypeConverter t = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(int));
            Console.WriteLine(t.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)));` return?

Comment: @mjwills it returns true ! thats strange! why the opposite one returns false ?!

Comment: Because one asks whether the string converter can convert to int. And the other asks whether the int converter can convert from string.

Comment: @mjwills string converter logically SHOULD can convert to int ! because string can convert to int like "123" to 123 .but it seems it can not !

Comment: I logically should be able to lift 100kg. But alas I can not. Things aren't always the way we wish they were. _On a serious note - the docs are pretty clear - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.stringconverter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4 ._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if Convert.ChangeType will work between two types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399273/test-if-convert-changetype-will-work-between-two-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddities of the implementation of `CanConvertFrom` aside, in your context you wouldn't get much help by knowing that a certain conversion could be performed until you try it. A converter cannot give you a definitive answer based on the type alone, for the same reason that there is no single answer to the question "can a string be converted to integer": the answer is "it depends on the string" - i.e. string `"123"` can be converted to `int`, while strings `"hello"` and `"1234567891011121314151617181920"` cannot be converted to `int`.

In other words, the answer could be obtained only when you know the value being converted. In your case it means putting `try`/`catch` block around your call of `Convert.ChangeType`, and interpreting each of the four exceptions it could throw ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: I wanted to get rid of try/catch, to make my code more clear.
Also I am not going to check just int. I needed to check conversion of string to unknown types. but because in int it does not work as I expected , i mentioned int.

Comment: @Parsa I realize that you wanted to get rid of try/catch from your question, and tried explaining why it cannot be done in general case. That is, at least until `Convert` adds `TryChangeType` or a similar non-throwing method.

Answer (score 1):

A `StringConverter` only cares about `string`. What you would need is `System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter`. It is `Int32Converter` that cares about `int`. `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(int))` gives you that.

Essentially, a `TypeConverter` is usually used to format a target type to display, or to parse input back to that target type. There's nothing much involved in displaying or parsing a string to/from a string, so you will be unsurprised to hear that `StringConverter` does very little! Here, the interesting type is `int`, and `Int32Converter` knows how to format an `int` for display, and parse an `int` from input.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.stringconverter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) for `StringConverter` state:

> This converter can only convert to a string. It works as a pass
>   through for other converters that want to convert an object to a
>   string.

[`Int32Converter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.int32converter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4), on the other hand, states:

> This converter can only convert a 32-bit signed integer object to and
>   from a string. The Int32 value type represents signed integers with
>   values ranging from negative 2,147,483,648 through positive
>   2,147,483,647.

As such `Int32Converter` is likely what you want to use, rather than `StringConverter`.

Alternatively, consider writing a `Convert.TryChangeType` extension method, with a `try catch` block in it - this will avoid you having to worry about the individual converters. In effect you will 'try it and see'. *This is especially important when doing conversions where you aren't sure whether they will work until runtime (e.g "abc" to int).*