# Cast to dynamic list with reflection c#

Tags: c#, reflection

How to cast a `List` of X object, based on the name in string?

I have this case:

```
public void AssignValue(string className, Dataset.Table table){
    Type currentType = Type.GetType("Namespace." + className);
    var objectCasted = (List<currentType.GetType()>)result;
}
```

Then, I'm trying to cast a `List` of a dynamic object, how I can do it using reflection?

Comment: seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398796/casting-with-reflection?

Comment: Do you mean `dynamic` as in the type, or "dynamic" in the sense of "determined at runtime"? What have you tried?

Comment: @ Sebastian I read it, but how to use with a list, is not specified

Comment: @CodeCaster based in a classname as string

Comment: Yeah so see duplicates. Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a new question, then if you do ask one, show what you have tried.

Comment: You can´t do this. Casting is a compile-time-_opertation and requires the type being know at compile-time. Maybe you want to *convert* the  items in the list. Have you seen this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925718/c-dynamic-runtime-cast?

Comment: If  you want to get the list type: `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(currentType)`, but what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @vc74 I want to bind it into a group of models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast to a type that is not known at compile time. Since your object is a List, it implements `IList` which might be good enough to allow you to access to the methods and properties you need: