# Can you pass an IEnumerable<Type> and retrieve the Type?

Tags: c#, system.type

I have some classes that use inheritance as in
Teacher : Person : Entity : BaseObject
Student : Person : Entity :BaseObject
Company : Entity : BaseObject etc.
The base object has an abstract IEnumerable property called Hierarchy
Entity class implements Hierarchy as `new List<Type>() { typeof(Entity) };`
Person class implements Hierarchy as `new List<Type> { typeof(Person), typeof(Entity)};` etc. 
In my db.Save method I am trying to cast the object to each of these types in turn so I can call the correct stored procedure.

```
        public static void SaveObject(BaseObject obj)
    {
        foreach (var type in obj.Hierarchy) //obj.Hierarchy is   IEnumerable<Type>
        {
            Object o = obj as type;
            //.....
        }
    }
```

but I get an error 'type is a variable but is used like a type'. Is there any way I can cast my child object to one of its parent types along these lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['casting' with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398796/casting-with-reflection)

Comment: Thanks. The first answer in that link didn't work because my classes don't implement IConvertible. The second answer from @Rafael looked promising but if I change `object o = obj as type` to `dynamic o = cast(type, obj)` and step through the code, even though type changes from Person to Entity as expected, o is still a Person not an Entity after that cast.

Comment: The penny drops. I've asked the Cast method to convert from type Person to type Entity but o is still of type Person afterwards. On reflection (if you'll pardon the pun) type Person 'IS' an Entity so the cast has actually worked, just not in the way I want. Might have to step back and come at this from another angle.